# Creating a private pod with a dependency on RestKit

Tags: restkit, cocoapods, podspec

Trying to add a podspec to my private repo that includes RestKit as a dependency, the validation always fails with many errors and warnings.
The errors occur when the validation process tries to run xcodebuild.

I used the command:

> pod repo push MYSpecs MY.podspec --verbose

Is there a way to skip validation when pushing to local repos?

Comment: There is `--allow-warnings` for pushing to private repo (e.g. to omit licence / webpage), however errors should be fixed - can you include what errors are you getting?

Comment: I found a temporary workaround adding the two flags:
--allow-warnings --use-libraries.

Will investigate and try to find a complete answer for this behaviour.